# How to add cell's detailText with left and right alignment (both) in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want to take a table the following cells:

```
The_main_cell_text_1
Detail_1           Detail_2
The_main_cell_text_2
Detail_3   Another_Detail_4
```

How to add cell's detailText with left and right alignment (both)?

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...<dynamic_space>...%@", detail_1, detail_2];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you should subclass uitableviewcell and add three custom labels to the contentview.

But to stay in your string based approach you could calculate the size of your two strings [string sizeWithFont: ...] and then calculate the appropriate count of spaces needed to have the look of a left aligned and a right aligned text.

approach 3 could be to just add one additional label onto cell.contentView, ehich is right aligned.